# Open source Android app

Tags: android, dictionary

Does anybody know an open source app which I can download and use as a starting point?

I just want to add comments on a map. When I m at a bar for example, I want to open the app, see where I am on a map and be able to leave a comment which will be shown to other logged in users. Logged in users can reply to my comment.

Not too familiar with android development, that s why I need something to start with.

App or tutorial sources would be great.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_and_open-source_Android_applications

Answer (score 2):

you could use PassAndroid as a starting point: https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid - also includes a map

Answer (score 1):

Github has a vast amount of [repositories with Android code](https://github.com/search?q=android) in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start with this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/), to learn how to use maps on android.

After that, you can search for [android projects on git hub](https://github.com/search?q=android).

Also, you need to learn how to work with web services, for every user can get the information in any device.